# How do I open the content without changing the domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

How do I open the content without changing the domain?
example:
User open `domain1.com/test.php` but to take the content `domain2.com/test.php` ?
htaccess or php script?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're looking to do:

If you want to permanently have calls to `domain1.com/test.php` redirect to `domain2.com/test.php`, you can set an A record in the DNS settings at your hosting provider. Be sure to use a 301 (not 302) redirect type.

If you simply want to have `domain1.com/test.php` return the payload from `domain2.com/test.php`, have `domain1.com/test.php` call `domain2.com/test.php` like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://domain2.com/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Comment: if test.php?id=100 or id=200 ?

Comment: or $_SESSIONS ... ??

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in these comments.

Comment: I want a substitute(Alternative Methods) on CNAME

Comment: You can't use CNAME records with naked domains.

Comment: Google Domains has created a CNAME-like synthetic record that works on naked domains. But it's generally best to avoid CNAME records if you can.

Comment: Then use the second solution I explained above.